# How To Upload Vue.js project in Live Server

Tags: vue.js

I believe it is much the same as a vue.js 2.6 upload. I have my setup as follows, is this correct? Is the only file I need to amend the index.html file which in my case is in the techjobs folder? I have amended this file to suit the directory structure. Are there any other files.Please provide .htaccess file

Comment: Upload Vue.js project in Live Server, what do you mean? To serve the project to a server as static files?

Comment: You haven't entered any code, so edit your question and complete it with the code you are apparently asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what are you asking, could you try to modify tour question, please?

Anyways, if what do you want is to know the way to compile and push to a production environment, there are several options like Firebase, Netlify, Github pages, etc.

You can use this documentation where you can follow step by step how to push to production.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines